# How to overwrite previously created newText object

Tags: random, lua, coronasdk

Here I'm creating a button with a function called when button is pressed

```
local politeButton = widget.newButton
{

left = 35,
top = 335,
width = 70,
height = 70,
defaultFile = "images/politeRu.png",
overFile = "images/politeWhiteRu.png",
onPress = politeGenerator,
}
```

and here's the function (actually it's coded up above the button)

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
local function politeGenerator()

local firstRandomPart = math.random(1,3)
local secondRandomPart = math.random(1,3)
local thirdRandomPart = math.random(1,3)

local firstComplPart = {"I love", "I need", "I beg"}
local secondComplPart = {" you like mad ", " the color of your eyes ", " your lips "}
local thirdComplPart = {"and I wish you are going to be mine!", "and I am shivering!", "and this is all I want!"}

local politeCompliment = firstComplPart[firstRandomPart]..secondComplPart[secondRandomPart]..thirdComplPart[thirdRandomPart]

local complimentItself = display.newText(politeCompliment, 30, 150, 200, 200, "Lobster", 18)

end
```

Ok, now I see some randomly generated text in the simulator. But when I press the button once again the old text doesn't disappear and new text is appear on the old text and so on. But I need text to be overwritten every time press the button. I tried `event.phase == "began"`, I tried `complimentItself:removeSelf()` but all in vain. Can anyone help, please? I just don't understand why the variable doesn't get overwritten when I press the button.

Comment: Is `complimentItself` the new widget that contains the text you just created? If so you lose your reference to it when the function exits and you can't remove it later. So each time through the function you create a new widget and never remove the old ones. You need to keep the old reference around and remove it from the display I would imagine (though I know nothing about corona).

Comment: Etan, thanks for your participation, your suggestion makes sense to me, but I still don't get "how to" or I don't understand where's exactly my mistake.

Comment: You either use a global (or outer local) to store the old reference and remove it when politeGenerator is run again or you find out how to hook up some other mechanism (event, signal, etc.) to let the text widget know that it needs to remove itself. I can't be more specific since I don't know enough about corona. The global/outer local route is certainly simplest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change your text by using `.text` to change the old text i re coded your code with a timer to see that the text is changing, the problem of your code is when you call the `politeGenerator()` function is you always initialize a local variable `complimentItself`  it will not overwrite the existing text but rather create a new one overlapping the old text

```
local firstComplPart = {"I love", "I need", "I beg"}
local secondComplPart = {" you like mad ", " the color of your eyes ", " your lips "}
local thirdComplPart = {"and I wish you are going to be mine!", "and I am shivering!", "and this is all I want!"}

local politeCompliment = firstComplPart[firstRandomPart]..secondComplPart[secondRandomPart]..thirdComplPart[thirdRandomPart]
local complimentItself = display.newText(politeCompliment, 30, 150, 200, 200, "Lobster", 18)


local function listener()

 politeCompliment = firstComplPart[math.random(1,3)]..secondComplPart[math.random(1,3)]..thirdComplPart[math.random(1,3)]
 complimentItself.text = politeCompliment
end

timer.performWithDelay( 1000, listener, 0 )
```

Comment: Yes! This helps! Thank you! Here I just need to place the function a complimentItself in a right place in the code and everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this function to create and update text objects. It's very simple:

```
function createText( text, xPos, yPos, fontSize, color, refPoint )
    local myText = display.newText( "", 0, 0, native.systemFont, fontSize )
    myText.text = text
    if refPoint == "CL" then
        myText:setReferencePoint( display.CenterLeftReferencePoint )
    elseif refPoint == "CR" then
        myText:setReferencePoint( display.CenterRightReferencePoint )
    elseif refPoint == "C" then
        myText:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
    end
    myText.x = xPos
    myText.y = yPos

    if color then myText:setTextColor( color[1], color[2], color[3] ) 
    else myText:setTextColor(255, 255, 255) end

    function myText:update( t, refPoint )
        myText.text = t.text or myText.text
        myText.size = t.fontSize or myText.size

        if refPoint == "CL" then
            myText:setReferencePoint( display.CenterLeftReferencePoint )
        elseif refPoint == "CR" then
            myText:setReferencePoint( display.CenterRightReferencePoint )
        elseif refPoint == "C" then
            myText:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
        end

        myText.x    = t.xPos or myText.x
        myText.y    = t.yPos or myText.y
    end

    return myText
end
```

Example:

```
local myText = createText( "Random text", 50, 160, 20, { 0, 0, 0 }, "C" )
myText:update( { text = "Updated random text", size = 30, xPos = 400, yPos = 300 }, "C" )
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I'm going to play around with your function to see if it is fit some of my needs!